# Save method manytomany

Tags: python, django, methods, save, many-to-many

I've got a model called Card which has a ManyToMany relationship to 
Tag. When I save a Card, I'd like to create a Product as well, which I 
want to have the same ManyToMany relationship to tag.

How do I access the instance's tags? `self.tags.all()` gives an empty 
list, while if I check after saving, the card actually has tags. My 
code is below. For the record, I am using Django 1.0.5.

```
class Card(models.Model): 
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product, editable=False, null=True) 
    name       = models.CharField('name', max_length=50, unique=True, help_text='A short and unique name or title of the object.') 
    identifier = models.SlugField('identifier', unique=True, help_text='A unique identifier constructed from the name of the object. Only change this if you know what it does.', db_index=True) 
    tags       = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name='tags', db_index=True) 
    price      = models.DecimalField('price', max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, db_index=True) 
    def add_product(self): 
        product = Product( 
            name = self.name, 
            identifier = self.identifier, 
            price = self.price 
        ) 
        product.save() 
        return product 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        # Step 1: Create product 
        if not self.id: 
            self.product = self.add_product() 
        # Step 2: Create Card 
        super(Card, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
        # Step 3: Copy cards many to many to product 
        # How do I do this? 
        print self.tags.all() # gives an empty list??
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the django-admin to save the model and tags? The many-to-many fields don't get saved there until after the post-save signal of the model. What you can do in this case is overide the admin classes save_model method. E.g.:

```
class CardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        #from this point on the tags are accessible
        print obj.tags.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding any tags to the Card. You can't add ManyToMany relationships until after you save the Card, and there's no time between the `save` call and the call to `self.tags.all()` for them to be set.