# Post save process using ManyToMany with intermediary model in admin

Tags: python, django, orm, entity-relationship

I have a model relationship as defined by the examples in the Django docs on ManyToMany relationship with an intermediary model.

I know how this normally works, but this is a quick little app that only uses the Django Admin and this is causing a slight bump in the road.

Here is what I have:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    vat_deductable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Relation)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    vat_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paid_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='SoldItem')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.customer) + u'_' + unicode(self.date)

class SoldItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
```

Here is what I would like to do:

After all models have been saved (the new instance of the parent model, any new instances of related models and any new instances of intermediary models) I would like to loop over all instances of `Item` that is associated with the newly saved Invoice so I can add their price and maybe VAT to the two fields `Invoice.amount` and `Invoice.vat_amount`

How would I do that? I have tried with custom save methods on both the `Invoice` model and its ModelAdmin form, but neither place gives the complete picture when new relations are being formed.

Maybe a signal? But which?

EDIT:
I have tried this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2109177/150033

It would make sense that save_m2m would make sure everything is saved, but it seems that the newest relationship is always missing when trying this.

Comment: From your example, it seems like you only need a post_save signal on Invoice. That would give you access to all of the items, and the pk for the invoice, that you could use to create new Sold Item records. If you're only wanting to create one SoldItem for all of the products that are the same, and just increment the qty, you could use get_or_create to look for previous SoldItem records for that invoice and update the quantity if a new record was not created.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you right, but I am not creating the SoldItem in my own code, the Admin is doing that. I just want to know when it is all done.

Comment: I see. Will adding a post_ave signal on SoldItem not do what you're needing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after much research I found someone else that solved this  http://igorsobreira.com/blog/2011/2/12/change-object-after-saving-all-inlines-in-django-admin/

In the invoice admin:

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        SoldItemAdmin,
    ]

    def response_add(self, request, new_object):
        obj = self.after_saving_model_and_related_inlines(new_object)
        return super(InvoiceAdmin, self).response_add(request, obj)

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        obj = self.after_saving_model_and_related_inlines(obj)
        return super(InvoiceAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)

    def after_saving_model_and_related_inlines(self, obj):
        solditem_changed.send(obj)
        return obj
```

And our signal:

```
solditem_changed = Signal()
@receiver(solditem_changed)
def update_invoice(sender, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(sender, 'solditem_set'):
        total = 0
        for item in sender.solditem_set.all():
            total += item.item.price * item.qty
        sender.amount = total
        sender.save()
    else:
        sender.amount = 0
        sender.save()
```

Comment: BTW, this does test out and works fine in the admin.  Updates and deletions are properly updating the amount on the invoice.

Comment: Nice suggestions. I do think I already tried the first one. Since SoldItemAdmin is an inline it doesn't seem to use its methods. That doesn't make any sense, I know, but what ever I did nothing happened. I will try you other suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, the inline admin breaks all that.  Seems like there's a lot of traffic on this specific issue in the community, but doesn't seem to be any resolution that actually works.  Boo!  I'll keep plugging, because I have a use for the same bits of code for a couple of my projects here at the office.

Comment: I have it working now, building on the suggestion by Brandon with the post_save on the SoldItem model. It is basically calling the combining method of the Invoice model with every save or delete of any SoldItem. This is not at all elegant, but it works. It will cause the calc method (which touches the DB) to run on every item added to the invoice and not just once per invoice save. I can post the code if you like.

Comment: Yeah, I was sticking with the admin because that's what you originally wanted a solution for.  The save on the model makes the most sense since it's not limiting you to a specific interface.